# Remove app from Google Play Region can they Still Purchase IAPs?

Tags: in-app-purchase, google-play-console, region

If I remove an app from a country or region in the Google Play Console

1. will users in that area still receive updates?
2. can they still make in app purchases?

I have searched all the google support articles as they are a bit vague or they contradict themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I think country/region available is unique to specific version of application. So if the given user will have the application version that is available in his region, he will be able to make purchases. As to recieving updates he will recieve update only if the updated version of the application will have his region included.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).